# shorter clearer way to array elemets to enum or vise verse

Tags: typescript

I need an array of roles and to pass a function I need type of one role. Can you suggest more elegant and cleaner way ?

```js
const roles = ["admin", "user", "moder"];
export type RoleType = "admin" | "user" | "moder";
```

or

```js
export type RoleType = "admin" | "user" | "moder";
const roles: RoleType[] = ["admin", "user", "moder"];
```

Answer (score 1):

In such situations, where we have a definite list of values, I prefer using a TypeScript `enum` type. However, using an array, you may do like this.

```
const roles = ["admin", "user", "moder"] as const;

export type RoleType = typeof roles[number];
```

`as const` makes the array "readonly" and like a tuple.

Correction, as suggested by @nerkn:

`roles[string]` should actually be `roles[number]` because the array indices are numbers only.

More on this can be read here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html.

Comment: thanks I was fiddling more than it deserved, as const I would never guessed. I've changed typeof roles[string] to typeof roles[number]

Comment: @nerkn, thanks for suggesting to change it to `number`. I have accepted your edit and added some context to it.